# Planes arrive at the rate of 5 an hour, what is the probability there will be no plane in the next 20 mins?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assuming that the planes arrive randomly at the rate of 5 an hour, what is the probability that there will be no plane in the sky for the next 20 minutes?

Comment: Are we assuming the planes arrive according to a Poisson process? If so you are looking for $\mathbb P(T_1>1/3)$ where $T_1$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with mean $1/5$.

Comment: You need to add more context.  Are you assuming, say, that the arrivals are governed by a Poisson process with average $5$?  Alternatively, are you saying that we know that exactly $5$ planes are arriving and that each arrival is drawn, indepedently, from a uniform distribution?  Something else?

Comment: $X \sim \mathsf{Pois}(5/3).$ You seek $P(X=0) = e^{-5/3}= 0.1888756.$

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I will assume that your question follows the poisson distribution. We'll 'cosmetically adjust' the rate of arrival to 5 per 60 minutes.

[image]

in this case just lay what we know:

```
lambda = 5/(60/20) 
e=2.718
x=0 (no planes at all)
```

so you get: `P(x=0)=e^-(5/3) = 0.188`